# How to label vertices on a mesh with user defined values?

Tags: visualization, mesh

I am trying to [write a code to estimate geometric properties (i.e. Mean Curvature, Gaussian Curvature, Principle Curvatures) on a triangulated mesh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117884/27951).

I would like to save the calculated data as a set of "Properties" to a given vertex within a mesh, which would allow for easier data storage and visualisation afterwards.

Something like this would be great:

```
SetProperty[{mesh,vertex1},"MeanCurvature"-> H ]

SetProperty[{mesh,vertex1},"GaussianCurvature"-> G ]
```

It seems like in graphs this is possible (see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PropertyValue.html#478575247) for example), however I am not too sure how to set properties for mesh objects. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is possible to do this, but it is not at all clear to me what the correct way to do it is.  For example, `mesh2 = SetProperty[{mesh, {1, All}}, 
  "foo" -> RandomReal[1, MeshCellCount[mesh, 1]]]`.  Then I can do `PropertyValue[{mesh2, {1, {3,4}}}, "foo"]` to retrieve that property for edges 3 and 4. But if I do `PropertyValue[{mesh2, 1}, "foo"]`, I simply get `Automatic`.  `PropertyValue[{mesh2, {1, All}}, "foo"]` does work.  One might think that this is related to whether the property is associated with "edges in general", or with individual edges. ...

Comment: ... but that is inconsistent with how both `PropertyValue[{mesh2, 1}, MeshCellMeasure]` and `PropertyValue[{mesh2, {1,All}}, MeshCellMeasure]` return the same thing.  I think a clear description of how mesh properties work is very much needed, in conjunction with a complete list of built-in properties and an explanation of how and when these behave differently from user-defined properties.

Comment: @Szabolcs Among all `Names["*"]`, the following mesh properties make sense: `{MeshCellCentroid, MeshCellHighlight, MeshCellLabel, MeshCellMarker, 
MeshCellMeasure, MeshCellQuality, MeshCellShapeFunction, 
MeshCellStyle}`